# XML - remove node and it's content based on pattern

Tags: xml, awk, sed, xml-parsing

i want to remove nodes that are between the value or 21 and 22. also, the sub content also must be delete. i tried using many ways such as awk or sed. but it only removes that line, leaving the content behind.
From this http://pastebin.com/9E7Cj4tP to http://pastebin.com/A3xScxHt

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sed` or `awk`, use an XML-aware tool. For example, I was able to get the expected output with [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open input.xml ;
rm //imgdir[@name=21 or @name=22] ;
save output.xml ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar with `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//imgdir[@name=21 or @name=22]'
```